# Displaying json into table using Carto?

Tags: carto, attribute-table, json, carto-js

I am new to cartodb and i don't understand how to populate a bootstrap table with my json data retreived using sql.execute:

```
sql.execute("SELECT sonde.the_geom,sonde.nom,sonde_data.time,sonde_data.cod,sonde_data.fluo FROM sonde, sonde_data WHERE sonde.nom = sonde_data.ref_id_nom AND sonde.cartodb_id = '"+selection+"' ORDER by time").done(function(data) {

for (i in data.rows){
                nom.push(data.rows[i].nom)
                fluo.push(data.rows[i].fluo)
                cod.push(data.rows[i].cod)
                time.push(data.rows[i].time)
            }

        console.log(data)
        //////////////TABLE//////////////
        $(function () {
        $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
            //method: 'get',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            height: 400,
            striped: true,
            pagination: true,
            pageSize: 50,
            pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
            search: true,
            showColumns: true,
            showRefresh: true,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            clickToSelect: true,
            columns: [{
                field: 'data.nom',
                title: 'nom',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'bottom',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'data.fluo',
                title: 'fluo',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                sortable: true,

            }, {
                field: 'data.cod',
                title: 'cod',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true

            }]
        });
        });

        })
        }
        );


enter code
```

I am unable to display my data into the table, i don't know how to call it...
Could someone give me the clue please?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already looping through `data.rows`, which contains the data, this looks more like a Bootstrap question. I've just done an [example of html table from CartoDB SQL API data with plain JS](http://bl.ocks.org/juanignaciosl/574655d396d44803de30):

`<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var sql = cartodb.SQL({ user: 'documentation' });
    sql.execute("select adm0name, name from ne_10m_populated_places_simple_1 limit 10")
        .done(function(data) {
           data.rows.map(function(r) {
             var row = document.createElement('tr');
             var nameCell = document.createElement('td');
             nameCell.innerText = r.name;
             row.appendChild(nameCell);
             table.appendChild(row);
           });
        })
  </script>`